# MvxVisibility doesn't work correctly

Tags: android, win-universal-app, mvvmcross

I have a custom visibility converter.

```
public class BackupDateVisibilityConverter : IMvxValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var backupDate = (DateTime)value;
            var test = backupDate == new DateTime() ? MvxVisibility.Collapsed : MvxVisibility.Visible;
            return test;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

It returns correctly first MvxVisibility.Collapsed  and after I update the value MvxVisibility.Visible. But strangly the element is visible when Collapsed is returned and hidden when visible is returned.
On Windows it is completly ignored.

This is my binding:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  local:MvxBind="Visible BackupDateVisibility(BackupLastModified)">
```

When I bind Visibility instead of Visible it just doesn't work at all as on windows.

and

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
          Margin="0,15,0,7"
          Visibility="{Binding BackupLastModified, Converter={StaticResource BackupDateVisibilityConverter}}">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try inheriting from `MvxBaseVisibilityValueConverter` - see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Value-Converters#the-mvx-visibility-valueconverters

Comment: I did. Then the windows solution throws a Failed to resolve type MvvmCross.Platform.UI.IMvxNativeVisibility exception. The Android version works as long as I use Visibility and not Visble to bind.

Comment: Ah, I recognised that I forgot to register the plugin. Now it works. Thanks Stuart! =)